# Alternative backcolor broken after sorting using jQuery datatable plugin

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I am using the jquery datatable plugin. I have the following code that sets up alternative backcolor on an html table.

```
$('#dependenciesTabletr:odd td').addClass('odd');
$('#dependenciesTabletr:even td').addClass('even');

$('#dependenciesTable').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "aaSorting": [[2, "desc"]],
    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "bSortClasses": false,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "Filter:"
    },
    "bSort": true
});
```

The issue is after I sort the alternative backcolor is broken. is there anyway to reset this after each sort ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the css for this?

```
table.display tr.odd.gradeA {
    background-color: #ddffdd;
}

table.display tr.even.gradeA {
    background-color: #eeffee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm but take a look at this [example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html) this plugin provides the odd/even selectors outofthebox you don't need to bind them.

Comment: but where would you specify which colors  you want for the alternative rows?